# Prisma FindMany Where OR - ensure that at least X conditions met?

Tags: prisma

I've been spending a lot of time digging through the prisma docs, but can't find the answer I'm looking for. I've got a prisma query that looks like this:

```
const recommendedGames = await prisma.game.findMany({
        where: {
            OR: [
                ...keywordConditions,
            ],
            AND: {
                // some other condition
            },
        },
        select: {
```

Where "keywordConditions" is an array that contains objects that look something like this ("aStringField" is always the same value, the "some keywords" conditions are generated in another part of the code):

```
{
    aStringField: {
        contains: "some keyword",
    },
}
```

Is there a way to ensure that at least 3 (or whatever number) of these conditions are met within this OR? Essentially, I only want `recommendedGames` to be populated if it can match against at least one record that has at least 3 matching keywords / OR conditions. Right now it finds a record if at least 1 condition passes, but I'd like to be stricter than that. Alternatively, a solution where I could `orderBy` the number of matching conditions would be great, but I still can't figure out how to reference the number of conditions met to make that work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:-

```
    await prisma.game.findMany({
  where: {
    OR: [
      // 1st combo of conditions
      {
        AND: [
          {
            field1: {
              contains: "condition1",
            },
          },
          {
            field1: {
              contains: "condition2",
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      // 2nd combo of conditions
      {
        AND: [
          {
            field1: {
              contains: "condition2",
            },
          },
          {
            field1: {
              contains: "condition3",
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      // 3rd combo of conditions
      {
        AND: [
          {
            field1: {
              contains: "condition3",
            },
          },
          {
            field1: {
              contains: "condition1",
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  select: {},
});
```

New Explanation:-

Here I am now matching against 1 string field only but with different combination patterns using AND.

Comment: I edited my answer with some more information, but I'm always running the conditions against a single field containing a string. But this would work great if there were multiple fields to query against.

Comment: Now, I understand your query completely. You wanna match against one string field but with different combination of conditions, and At least 3 conditions at a time (In my answer I have taken only 2 conditions, for combination, at a time).

Please check the answer now. I have tried another solution and edited my answer.